# mysql dataSource remove quotes from parameter using select with IN clause

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

It seems that the mysql select parameter is being inserted with double quotes

```
string strEstablishments = String.Join(",", myEstablishments);
```

strEstablishments contains (from the VS2019  debug window)

```
"'1007','3'"


sqlDSselectEstablishment.SelectParameters.Add("Establishments", strEstablishments);

sqlDSselectEstablishment.SelectCommand = "SELECT EstablishID,Description FROM tblEstablishment WHERE EstablishID IN (@Establishments)";
```

But this doesn't give the result expected it only returns one result that the dropdown is populated with but should return two (establishments 1007 and 3)

It seems to me the double quotes around the string are being injected which would explain the returned results, I've tried removing them using `strEstablishments.Replace("\"","")` with no joy.

Running the below command from MySQL directly returns the results as expected:

```
SELECT EstablishID,Description FROM tblEstablishment WHERE EstablishID IN ('3','1007');
```

Any ideas how I can get the result as expected using asp.net

Comment: You cannot use a parameter to express the series of values required by the IN clause. You need a parameter for each value to pass

Comment: thanks perhaps I should of thought of doing that instead!

Comment: In the duplicate the second answer seems a pretty simple solution, but I would check the performance if you have a lot of parameters.